# Can't swap div elements using .innerHTML properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html / css / javascript and was making a website. I have divs that I call video panels because on each panel there's a video and a caption. I am trying to write a script that when called grabs the contents of the panels and places the contents of the next panel (on each click) where the contents of the 0th panel would be (all are hidden but the 0th panel in the array, trying to make each next panel appear on click).

This is my first question, sorry if it's worded weird and thanks for the help!

```js
var counter = 0;

function nextSlide() {
    var panel0 = document.getElementById("panel0").innerHTML;
        panel1 = document.getElementById("panel1").innerHTML;
        panel2 = document.getElementById("panel2").innerHTML;
        panel3 = document.getElementById("panel3").innerHTML;
        panel4 = document.getElementById("panel4").innerHTML;
    var panels_contents = [panel0, panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4];
    if (counter < 4) {
        var switcher = panels_contents[counter + 1];
            original = panels_contents[0];
        panels_contents[0] = switcher;
        panels_contents[counter + 1] = original;
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }

}
```

```css
#panel1 { display: none; } 
#panel2 { display: none; } 
#panel3 { display: none; } 
#panel4 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="video-panel" id="panel0">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
        rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="captions">
      <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot</p>
      <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
</div>


<button onclick="nextSlide();">Press me</button>
```

Comment: could you add all the code , and update the error's in the console if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have updated your code . you can use below code it will work for you

```js
var counter = 0;
    function nextSlide() {
        var nextSlide = counter + 1 ;
        if (nextSlide <= 4) {
            document.getElementById('panel'+counter).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('panel'+nextSlide).style.display = 'block';
            counter++;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            document.getElementById('panel4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('panel0').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

```css
#panel1 { display: none; } 
#panel2 { display: none; } 
#panel3 { display: none; } 
#panel4 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="video-panel" id="panel0">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
                rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="captions">
            <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot 0</p>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-panel" id="panel1">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
                rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="captions">
            <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot 1</p>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="video-panel" id="panel2">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
                rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="captions">
            <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot 2</p>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-panel" id="panel3">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
                rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="captions">
            <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot 3</p>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-panel" id="panel4">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe height="255px" width="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ENpPHGj3GbA        
                rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="captions">
            <p class="caption-head">Python Discord Bot 4</p>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <button onclick="nextSlide();">Press me</button>
```

```
function prevSlide() {
        var nextSlide = counter - 1 ;
        if (nextSlide >= 0) {
            console.log('counter',counter);
            console.log('nextSlide',nextSlide);
            document.getElementById('panel'+counter).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('panel'+nextSlide).style.display = 'block';
            counter--;
        } else {
            counter = 4;
            document.getElementById('panel4').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('panel0').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: if there are many more panels - then with this : `var panels = document.querySelectorAll("video-panel").length - 1; `  and instead of  `if (nextSlide <= 4)` we could do as `if (nextSlide < panels)`

Comment: yeah we can do this too

Comment: Thank you, going to try it right now Taylor.

Comment: It doesn't work properly, when I click my button it seems to move a line break that's in the code

Comment: but its working in example .. can you show us where exactly the issue is in your code . maybe a screenshot

Comment: I apologize, it required fixing the links to the videos, the formatting got messed up. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you as well Codenewbie, I will consider that if I add more panels!

Comment: Would it be relatively simple to add another function that goes back to the previous slide, so I can call that when a "back" button is clicked?

Comment: Yeah i guess you copy the same function and instead of increment you can use the decrement . i dont think you will have any issue

Comment: post me here in case of any issue

Comment: I added it and am trying to tamper with it to make it work. It doesn't work as planned, it first makes one video show up below the original instead of replacing it. After it seems to work

Comment: let me do this for you. give me 10 min please

Comment: I have added a piece of code to my answer you can copy that function and add this to your code .. let me know if you have any issue

Comment: it should work.. as its working for me .. please let me know what exactly the error is